# Ошибка Playground execution failed при декларировании required convenience init

Tags: swift3

Получаю ошибку

> Playground execution failed: MyPlaygroundDeleteLast6.playground:98:28: note: convenience initializer is declared here
>         required convenience init(_ string:String) { ...
>                              ^

на вот такой код:

```
class myClass {

  required convenience init(_ string:String) {

    self.init()
    print(string)
  }
}
class mySubclass: myClass {
}
```

Почему? Разве convenience init не должен просто наследоваться?

Answer (score 0):

> Разве convenience init не должен просто наследоваться?

Должен. Но так как Вы указали `required`, то необходимо переопределить все `designated` инициализаторы:

```
class MyClass {
    required convenience init(_ string:String) {
        self.init()
        print(string)
    }
}
class MySubclass: MyClass {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

либо уберите `required`

Comment: А почему? Из чего это следует?

Comment: @tmm из практической проверки. А почему второстепенный инициализатор Вы хотите required?